# Animation Nodes loops and Python

Tags: python, animation-nodes, loop

I am starting with the animation nodes and I am trying to replace as many nodes as possible with Python code; it is especially nice for the math. However, now I am stuck with the looping. Is it possible to replace the Loop Input and its generators with Python code plus other nodes? thanks

Comment: Hello, are you talking about "Expression" nodes (where you can only write one single line of code) or "Script" nodes, where you can write as many lines as you want in a text block ?

Comment: I understand that in Expression nodes one can put only one line of code so looping would be difficult but in scripting nodes it should be possible. I am just not sure how to reproduce the Loop input and generators in the script

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to know how to access input variables and how to output variables in the script. Otherwise it's just common python operations. Mainly you will have to use `for` [loops](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop).

Let's see how to emulate a loop with a python script, for example to output a list of the location of each object in a given collection.

Here in my collection I have 3 objects.

[image]

And here the simple setup to output their locations using a loop node :

[image]

Now, to do the same with a script node. Add your script node, add a text block with the + icon. Add a new input of type "Collection", I renamed it "col". Add a new output of type "Vector list", I renamed it "positions".

[image]

In a text editor, find your new script textblock and open it. Write a few lines to do the job.

```
positions = []

for obj in col.objects:
    positions.append(obj.location)
```

Or with list comprehension

```
positions = [obj.location for obj in col.objects]
```

Note that `col` hasn't been defined in this text block : AN gives it context since you told the script node that a variable named `col` will be available, as a collection type.

Similarly, you have to define the variable `positions` and at the end of the execution of the script, AN will automatically gather its value.

**/!\ `col` and `positions`are case sensitive**. They have to match the variable names you wrote in the script node.

Add an invoke node set to your script, execute the AN tree and voilà :

[image]